# How do I set up multiple threads in a Worker and dispatch messages to them?

Tags: c#, azure, task-parallel-library

I have lots of "jobs" in my system that are long-running but not CPU bound. I would like to set up a Worker role to handle these, but they are scalable enough that one Worker role could easily have 10-20 threads all processing a "job" at the same time.

There are questions here suggesting use of the TPL, which I do have some limited experience with. What I do not understand, however, is how to manage the threads so there is a max number of them, and how to dispatch them when one frees up.

Slightly complicating this is that I would like to use Ninject for creating the services each "job" needs.

Here is how I image it working in my head:

```
while (true)
{
    // Don't go unless we have a free slot (how do I implement this?!)
    if (FreeThreadExists)
    {
        // Get the next message
        CloudQueueMessage ThisMessage = Queue.GetMessage(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3));

        // Get the new job and inject services
        Job MyJob = Kernel.Get<Job>();

        // Start this job
        // Will I need to keep ahold of this Task?
        // And how do I know when it's done so that FreeThreadExists changes?
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => MyJob.Run(ThisMessage));
    }
    else
    {    
        // Sleep to prevent choking
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
}
```

Then in that thread delete the message on completion. Basically I'm trying to split off one Worker into 20 "instances" without losing too much Azure functionality (specifically I'd like the queue message timeout/retry functionality).

I am rather inexperienced in .NET threading, what is the best way to go about this?

Edit: Wow, I totally forgot to add an important point: this needs to scale across multiple Workers. So, 10 Worker roles, each with 10 threads, messages get queued by the UI front end, then dequeued and run by the first Worker with a free thread.

Comment: Just add all of the jobs to the thread pool and let it take care of the rest.  It will manage the scheduling, the creation of threads, etc.  I wouldn't bother doing any more unless you can demonstrate that it's a problem to just let the system handle it.  It's surprisingly good at such things.

Comment: I'm a dumbass, relevant info added to question. Sorry

Comment: Doesn't change my answer.  Just put all of the tasks you have into the thread pool and let it take care of it.  Chances are it will schedule them more effectively than you could, and it will save you the effort of even trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this pseudo code:

```
while (true)
{
    int maxThreadsPerWorkerRole = 3;//assuming each worker role can handle 3 jobs simultaneously
    var messages = Queue.GetMessages(3);//Get 3 messages from the queue
    if (messages != null && messages.Count > 0)//Ensuring there is some work which needs to be done
    {
        var myTasks = new List<Task>();
        for (int i=0; i<messages.Count; i++)
        {
            Job MyJob = Kernel.Get<Job>();//Get the job
            var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => MyJob.Run(messages[i])); 
            myTasks.Add(task);
        }
        Task.WaitAll(myTasks.ToArray());//Wait for all tasks to complete.
        for (int i=0; i<messages.Count; i++)
        {
            //Write code to delete the message.
        }
        //Check if the queue is empty or not. If the queue is not empty, then repeat this loop
        //Otherwise simply exit this loop.
        if (Queue.RetrieveApproximateMessageCount() == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I also usually involve the TPL, as you mentioned in your code. As an alternative to Gaurav's approach, see the code below. The pseudo-code below uses Parallel.For, which controls the thread creation. Each thread starts and runs an infinite loop; if there is no work, make sure you sleep a bit.

```
// Start 10 threads
Parallel.For(0, 10, (i) =>
{
  while (true)
  {
    // Get message from queue
    var msg = Queue.GetMessage();
    if (msg != null)
    {
      // Do some work here...
      StartSomeJob();

      // Then when you are done, delete the message
      Queue.DeleteMessage(msg);
    }
    // Wait 1 second before fetching next work item from queue
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
  }
});
```

Comment: Based on this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh767287.aspx maximum throughput for Azure queues is 2000 messages / second so I think the service can handle it. However since each get message will incur a transaction charge irrespective of the fact that you have message in the queue or not, you may want to take this fact into consideration and send request in somewhat sensible manner. Some folks have recommended an exponential back-off strategy for fetching messages from a queue.

Comment: In some performance tests I performed earlier, I was not able to get to 2000 msg/sec but I can confirm that I was able to get hundreds of hits/sec. Our scalability needs required us to shard on multiple queues across storage accounts. The point about the cost is a good one; a backoff stragey makes sense on this.  Another thing to consider is that you can dequeue up to 10 items at once; keep that in mind.